# Implementing simple service in Android

Tags: android, service, android-service

Let's say that I want to create a service (note: lowercase - I'm not implying a android.app.Service) on an Android device that queries a web API every 30 seconds and provides any updates to the subscribed Activity.  I only anticipate one Activity will ever be subscribed to this service.  Should I

1. Create a full on android.app.Service and bind my Activity to that Service? Or...
2. Create a lightweight "service" (lowercase) which is basically a thread that implements the observer pattern and periodically updates any registered observers (of which there should only ever be one) with new information.

URLs to online examples would also be appreciated.

Comment: Not totally related, but polling may have a negative impact on your battery life.  Have you considered C2DM for notifications instead?

Comment: @jglouie - It might be related. For the first iteration, I'm going to implement my (S|s)ervice in the most naïve way possible - but I might invest time into learning about C2DM later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Never expect your Activities to stay alive*

Your Activity should not start a Thread except for short-period offloading of work. The system may always suspend the Activity. You may thus not rely on an activity to keep running.

This pretty much means that a Thread is a no-go. Also note that Thread.sleep has no accuracy. It may misfire and wakeup too early or too late. See the [android:java.lang.Thread.sleep documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep%28long%29)

```
Causes the thread which sent this message to sleep
for the given interval of time (given in milliseconds).
The precision is not guaranteed - the Thread may sleep
more or less than requested.
```

Both facts pretty much destroy the Thread-based idea. I'd highly recommend that you look into the android Service infrastructure.

Comment: Very good information - do you have any further recommendations about *how* to implement via a android.app.Service? I understand that there are several options, but I don't know which to choose.  IntentService? Bound Service? ...

Answer (score 1):

Use the `IntentService` class / pattern. Create a `onHandleIntent` on your Activity which your `android.app.Service` instance will callback too and you're all set. Its lightweight and Android will take care of most of the housekeeping.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html

Comment: but it is my understanding that the client of the IntentService has to start the service each time I need to know if there's an update.  Rather, I would like the service to start up and notify the client at 30 second intervals if new data is available.

Comment: Well you have a chicken-n-egg: if there is no client around to receive the Service answer then what does it matter?

Answer (score 0):

I think an [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) can do all the work for you. You have a `doInBackgroud` method, where you can query your API and send process messages if you want and update in `onPostExecute`. There you can start a new `AsyncTask`.

Comment: Am I correct in that upon each return of AsyncTask I have to issue a new AsyncTask?

Comment: I would suggest to implement a Timer to do this

Answer (score 0):

I answered [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6461937/tutorial-for-android-services/6461995#6461995) question about services in the past. You could tie in AsyncTask into the service to handle the web query